# Prestashop Smarty get order price after checkout header.tpl

Tags: prestashop, smarty

I'm trying to implement bing ads on my website.

I need to add this script in header.tpl replacing GetRevenueValue with the order price

```
<script>
window.uetq = window.uetq || [];
window.uetq.push({ 'gv': GetRevenueValue(), 'gc': 'EUR'}); 
</script>
```

how can i get the total price of the order in smarty ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding the code in order_confirmation.tpl where the price is already defiened